# Can you extract bitmask directly from bitfield in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-fields, bitmask

Considering following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    uint8_t A:1;
    uint8_t B:1;
    uint8_t C:1;
    uint8_t D:1;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.A = 1;
    test.B = 0;
    test.C = 1;
    test.D = 0;
    
    int bitmask = test.A | (test.B << 1) | (test.C << 2) | (test.D << 3);
    
    cout << "Size: " << sizeof(test) << ", bitmask: " << bitmask;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that the data in the bitfield is represented as bitmask somehow? I was wondering if there is a way to get a bitmask directly, without having to go through and shift all members. In this case it's not a big deal, but if you have large bitfield it can get pretty tedious.

For example it would be great if I could do something like this:

```
int bitmask = (int)test;
```

Of course that doesn't work. Any way to achieve similar robustness?

Comment: "I'm assuming that the data in the bitfield is represented as bitmask somehow?" That doesn't even make sense. The data is a value. The bitfield *itself* has a bitmask that defines its extent in the word, but that's completely separate from the data in the bitfield. And why you need that bitmask when you already have the bitfield is a mystery, as is what you mean by "shift all members". Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 What he wants to do is convert the struct of bitfields to an int so that each one bit long bitfield appears in the int where it would go if you could convert the struct to an int.  But I am sure `int bitmask2 = *(int*)&test;` is UB since it is type punning

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It is up to the OP to clarify his question, not up to us to guess what he might mean.

Comment: @user207421 I wasn't guessing - I was rephrasing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert the entire struct, *and* there exists an integral type with the same size as the struct:

```
Test test;
test.A = 1;
test.B = 0;
test.C = 1;
test.D = 0;

cout << (int)std::bit_cast<char>(test) << '\n';
```

`std::bit_cast` is a C++20 feature.

`char` is used here because it has the same size as `Test`. I'm casting the result to `int`, because otherwise `cout` interpretes the resulting number as a character code.

---

The alternative solution is to `memcpy` the struct (or a part of it) to an integer:

```
char ch;
std::memcpy(&ch, &test, 1);
cout << (int)ch << '\n';
```

Unlike `bit_cast`, this doesn't require a modern compiler, and allows you to inspect a specific part of the struct (assuming the part is byte-aligned).